# Tenant Isolation with spark structured streaming

Tags: azure-synapse, delta, delta-live-tables, azure-synapse-analytics

I am currently exploring Azure Synapse Analytics, focusing on near-real-time (NRT). I am planning to utilize Delta tables and we have a multi-tenant setup for our product where each tenant's data should be isolated and processed independently.

Here are the specific challenges I'm facing with spark structured streaming in synapse:

- I need to run stream processing jobs separately for each tenant. The goal is to ensure that each tenant's data is processed independently to maintain data isolation. (**data at rest, in transit and during processing should be isolated**)
- Data Storage in Tenant-Specific Containers: For data storage, each tenant should have their data stored in a dedicated container (one container per tenant).

How can I configure spark structured streaming using Synapse to run separate stream jobs for each tenant, ensuring that each job only processes data for its respective tenant? Do we have any framework/feature in azure synapse/structured streaming that can help us here?

[image]